# Difference between Bayesian T-Test and Bayesian Informative Hypotheses Evaluation (BAIN) on JASP?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, t-test

I have three friends in an honours project and we are trying to perform a Bayesian Analysis.

I am doing a Welch’s T-Test due to very uneven group sizes, one is doing a linear regression and another is doing a one-way ANOVA. After performing these frequentist tests, we were hoping to also do a Bayesian analysis to get a better look into our data, and see what evidence we have for the null/alternative etc.

We cannot figure out how to do it on R, so we have downloaded JASP.

Under Bayesian T-Tests on JASP, there is no option for a “Welch’s T-Test.” However, I can do a BAIN analysis (Bayesian Informative Hypotheses Evaluation). The other two are able to do both, but get different ‘answers’ between the T-Test and the BAIN analysis.

We were wondering if there is a difference between what these two things are testing? We have trawled the internet to no avail! If there are differences, what is the better one to use post a null significance frequentist test?

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would reply to your question since it doesn't have any answers.

This problem is known as the Behrens-Fisher problem.  It has several possible solutions for a flat prior distribution on the difference.  The exact solution is to use the Behrens-Fisher distribution, for which you will be unable to find software.

Nonetheless, there is a close approximation.  Welch's t-test is one of those approximations.  The difference becomes one of interpretation.

Bayesian methods do not have a null hypothesis.  With a null hypothesis, you grant it a 100% certainty that it is true.  Then you bring out the data and ask how probable it would be to see the data if the null is true.

It has the form of $\Pr(X|\theta=\Theta)$, or it's equivalent for a one-sided test.  You assume the null is true, then find out how far away the data is from that point.  You take the opposite perspective with Bayesian methods.  If you have two hypotheses, Bayesian methods let you use as many as you can choose as long as the set is finite, then you end up with two partitions of the posterior distribution.  One of them is $\Pr(\theta\ge\Theta|X)$ and the other is $\Pr(\theta<\Theta|X)$.  Alternatively, $\Pr(\theta\le\Theta|X)$ and the other is $\Pr(\theta>\Theta|X)$.  Notice that there is no equal sign in there.

That is because, for a continuous distribution, $\Pr(\theta=\Theta)\equiv{0}$.  A probability is an area, and if it is exactly equal to $\Theta$, then there is no width, just height.

With a flat prior and a one-sided test, the Bayesian posterior probability would be one minus the p-value.  If the p-value were .04 of observing this data if the null is true, then the posterior probability would be that there is a 96% chance that the alternative hypothesis' region is the actual region.  That relationship works here, approximately, but that is not a generally true statement.  Usually, there is no direct one-to-one relationship between the Frequentist p-value and a Bayesian posterior.

That brings us to the informative alternative.

The big difference between a Frequentist probability and a Bayesian probability is that the Bayesian probability depends upon what you already know about the problem, ignoring Frequentist meta-analysis for the moment.

Let us imagine that some researcher has already asked this question and has results.  Why would you not incorporate that researcher's results in your calculations?  Why would you waste data and information just because it wasn't in your experiment?

Imagine there was a giant study with 100,000 participants that you decided to replicate.  You had 100 participants.  Do you really believe that your 100 participants have so much information in them that you could discard the other set of data?

The prior distribution encodes the information that you have that is outside the sample.  If you have prior knowledge of the problem, you must not use Welch's t-test because you are wasting information.  Welch's t-test only includes the results from your data.

You would then use BAIN.

That is why you are getting conflicting results.  With BAIN, you are adding in information; essentially, you are adding data to your sample that you do not really have.

The closest thing you have to a prior distribution on the Frequentist side of the coin is meta-analysis.